# React Native - navigation.addListner is not an object

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import Epics from './screens/tmp';
import Pager from './screens/Pager';

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
 Home: {screen: Epics},
 Page: {screen: Pager}
},{initialRouteName: 'Home'});

const Stack = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Stack />;
  }
}
```

Trying to invoke fetch API everytime a user lands on screen using navigation addListner event

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.loadFeed(); // fetch API
   const { navigation } = this.props;
   this.focus = navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
     this.loadFeed(); // fetch API
   });
}
```

React Navigation version from package.json:

- "react-navigation": "^4.2.2"
- "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.2"

Is there a better way to detect an active screen on app and invoke the fetch API? Or fix for the given error below?

**Type Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.addListner'):**
[Error when the app launches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rUuG.png)

## **Update**

I am trying to replicate following example in snack: https://snack.expo.io/HkrP8YPIf

What am I doing wrong? (I am new to React Native, please help me understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `NavigationEvents` component shipped with react-navigation 4.x. Just nest it anywhere inside your screen's render method.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

const MyScreen = () => (
  <View>
    <NavigationEvents
      onWillFocus={() => console.log('Screen will be in focus')}
      onDidFocus={() => console.log('Screen is in focus')}
      onWillBlur={() => console.log('Screen will blur')}
      onDidBlur={() => console.log('Screen blurred')}
    />
    {/*
      other code
    */}
  </View>
);

export default MyScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

This just means that `navigation` doesn't exist. So it looks like the component is supposed to receive it via props and isn't. That's all I can tell from this code.

Comment: I am new to React Native and I am trying to understand this. In the given snack example: snack.expo.io/HkrP8YPIf, this.prop is not explicitly defined, yet it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't user 'react-navigation' myself (I use a different package called 'react-native-navigation' which works a little differently). However, from this code it looks like your App component just renders Navigator. Navigator has some syntax that is specific to 'react-navigation', and looks like it's wrapping the components you made (FirstScreen and SecondScreen). This is where it'll be adding the prop navigation, which you then have access to in the component itself. Someone more familiar with this package can help you with your specific code, maybe. This is all I can really say.

Answer (score 0):

Check your props keys, agree with James. Have one suggestion here, since you're expecting a props, you should handle this common error whether key exist or not(if else)

Comment: I am new to React Native and I am trying to understand this. In the given snack example: https://snack.expo.io/HkrP8YPIf, this.prop is not explicitly defined, yet it works. What am I doing wrong?